# (Java) How to verify external link redirection with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

### Hi Guys!

Please take a look at my code, i'm trying to verify that my current webpage will be redirected to external site, in my case Google Play(open Google Play in the same tab). I guess i'm doing it wrong way cuz it pass with FireFox but failing with Chrome, here is my code...

```
String currentURL1 = driver.getCurrentUrl();

profilePage.clickOnGooglePlayLink();

String currentURL2 = driver.getCurrentUrl();

Thread.sleep(3000);

Assert.assertNotEquals(currentURL1, currentURL2, "Failed Redirected to Google Play");

log.info("Redirected to Google Play!");
```

I'm trying to assert it as NotEquals, is it any other solutin for this case?
Thanks for your time!
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6AtN.png)

Comment: Is new page is opening on same tab or diffrent ?

Comment: You can try to get title of those web page using `driver.gettitle()`

Comment: Hi Ankur, web page opening in the same tab. Thanks.

Comment: You can verifiy title also why are you checking for URL ?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty correct when the following line **Fails** :

```
Assert.assertNotEquals(currentURL1, currentURL2, "Failed Redirected to Google Play");
```

### Analysis

If you look at the documentation of **`assertNotEquals`**, the signature is either of the following :

- **`void org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals(Object actual1, Object actual2)`**
- **`void org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals(Object actual1, Object actual2, String message)`**

Here both the **`assertNotEquals()`** method takes **`Object`** as an `argument` and performs `evaluation`.

But in your code, instead of an **`Object`** you have passed **`currentURL1`** and **`currentURL2`** and both of them are **String** as follows :

```
String currentURL1 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
//
String currentURL2 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
//
Assert.assertNotEquals(currentURL1, currentURL2, "Failed Redirected to Google Play");
```

So when both the **Strings** are casted to **`Objects`**, the comparison **Fails** as **`assertNotEquals()`** method doesn't takes **`String`** as an `argument`.

### Solution

If you want to compare two **Strings**, a better option would be either of the following :

- **`void org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(String actual, String expected)`**
- **`void org.testng.Assert.assertEquals(String actual, String expected, String message)`**

Answer (score 1):

Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected, message):-  assertEquals assertion is useful to compare two string, boolean, byte[], char, double, float, int, etc.. and based on assertion result.

Assert.assertNotEquals(actual, expected, message) :-
 assertion in selenium WebDriver is assertNotEquals assertion. It's function is opposite to assertEquals assertion. **Means if both sides values will not match then this assertion will pass else it will fail**. Here you can write your own message for failure condition.

Please refer this [link](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/03/example-of-assertnotequals-in-selenium.html)